# pulseaudio --kill permission denied? (Something's using my soundcard and I don't know what it is.)

Tags: sound, permissions, pulseaudio

So, a few weeks ago I was having problems with skype and pulseaudio/alsa things, so I went to [this link](http://www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/7130/2) and found a way to supposedly kill and start pulseaudio at will. So, in etc/pulse/client.conf, I added this:

```
autospawn = no
daemon-binary = /bin/true
```

Then, I removed

```
/etc/rc2.d/S50pulseaudio
```

It worked at first, but now a few weeks have passed and I played audio through Hydrogen, presumably using PulseAudio (it never seems to need JACK), and now other sounds won't play, e.g. on Chrome.

Well, basically, these are all the things I tried:

```
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> pulseaudio --start
N: [pulseaudio] main.c: User-configured server at {b66743961e53727ca323de3b0000001b}unix:/home/apodio/.pulse/b66743961e53727ca323de3b0000001b-runtime/native, which appears to be local. Probing deeper.
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> sudo alsa force-reload
[sudo] password for apodio: 
/sbin/alsa: Warning: Processes using sound devices: 12442(jackd). 
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-rawmidi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device snd-page-alloc (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device snd-page-alloc).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-conexant snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-rawmidi snd-seq-midi-event snd-seq snd-timer snd-seq-device snd-page-alloc.
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> pulseaudio --kill
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> pulseaudio --start
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> sudo pulseaudio --start
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
E: [autospawn] core-util.c: Home directory /home/apodio not ours.
W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> sudo pulseaudio --kill
E: [pulseaudio] core-util.c: Home directory /home/apodio not ours.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to kill daemon: Permission denied
┌─( apodio ) - ( 3.2.0-43-generic ) - ( ~ )
└─> sudo pulseaudio --start
W: [pulseaudio] main.c: This program is not intended to be run as root (unless --system is specified).
E: [autospawn] core-util.c: Home directory /home/apodio not ours.
W: [autospawn] lock-autospawn.c: Cannot access autospawn lock.
E: [pulseaudio] main.c: Failed to acquire autospawn lock
```

I think I am root, since I'm the only user etc. I've also added myself to the audio group in a moment of haste.

PS I know it says "Processes using sound devices: 12442(jackd)", but I just started up qjackctl and as usual it said it couldn't connect, so I have a feeling it wasn't actually running.

But...autospawn lock? Permission denied? Home directory not ours? I'm the only user on this computer! What's going on?

Basically, since I used Hydrogen, something is now using my soundcard and I don't know what or how to stop it.